# Readonly Fields or Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Is there a way to have either a **read only Field** or a **Property with no setter** map to a database column with Entity Framework Code First?

I found both are ignored, example:

```
using System;

namespace App.Model
{
    public class Person
    {
        string _address1; // Private Field to back the Address Property

        public string Address1 // Public Property without a Setter
        {
            get { return _address1; }
        }


         public readonly string Address2; // Public Read Only Field
    }
}
```

Is there Fluent API call or another approach to accomplish?

Comment: Very good question. Glancing at the `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` methods it doesn't look promising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to make entities truly immutable, but you can use an inaccessible setter to stop users from modifying them, which might be good enough, depending on your situation:

```
public string Address1 // Public Property without a Setter
{
  get { return _address1; }
  internal set { _address1 = value; }
}
```

The Entity Framework will still be able to set the value, so it'll load properly, but once created the property will be more or less fixed.

(I recommend using an `internal` rather than `private` setter, so that you can still perform mappings with the Fluent API in your context or a configuration class, provided they're in the same assembly, or a friend assembly.)

Comment: Unfortunately private setters are ignored when they are inherited from a Base Class. I'm trying to determine a different approach that would work from my Base Class.

Comment: `internal` or `protected` setters should work, shouldn't they?  This is the approach I use for read-only entities, and it's worked pretty well even with a fairly deep inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: My goal is make the value immutable. I have audit columns on my database tables such as CreatedDate that once set I don't want updated. On insert I want to control how the value is set via a function, so I don't want the field/property updatable.

Comment: Well, any field is updateable with reflection (even `readonly` fields that are constructor-injected).  If someone is determined to mess with the innards of your classes, they'll find a way.  The best you can do is make it clear that you don't want them to.  Anyway, as a compromise you could have a `private` read/write property that's mapped to your database, and then an unmapped `public` read-only property that returns its value.  That's not really substantially different from my first suggestion, but it does kinda add one more layer.

Comment: As for your auditing purposes, you might be better off putting that sort of information in a separate history table that's not mapped at all.

Comment: Properties that are set to Private are ignored by EF.

Comment: I need to track the user that created the object and the application timestamp. If I was using StoredProcs I could pass this information to the proc, but I trying to keep with EF interacting with tables directly, so I need the audit fields in the Entities and as columns in the table. I'm not a fan of the one audit table approach that some use because of performance issues (bottleneck) and the break with 3rd normal form.

Comment: Not if they're mapped explicitly with the Fluent API.  But it doesn't make any difference for your purposes anyway -- they'd still be editable via reflection.

Comment: EF6 will include support for stored procedures for CRUD operations, that might be a way to go if your timeline can wait.

Comment: Do you know if the Fluent API would work if they the properties are defined in a Base Class? What would be syntax?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30602/discussion-between-jeremy-todd-and-josh)

Comment: Any changes in regard to EF7?